# How to solve this error (missing $)

Tags: tables, errors

An error keeps popping up while I was making my table. This is the code:

```
\begin{table}

\caption{Pearson’s coefficient of mechanical properties with different compositional parameters.}

\label{tab:4}

\begin{tabular}{lllllll}

\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

& \rho\textsubscript{w} & \rho\textsubscript{d} & \%Min & \%Ash & \%Org\textsubscript{w} & \%H\textsubscript{2}O\\ %this isthe faulty line!!

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

\textit{E} & 0.55\textsuperscript{a} & 0.92\textsuperscript{a} & 0.93\textsuperscript{a} & 0.81\textsuperscript{a} & -0.14 & 0.14\\

$\textit{k} & 0.31 & 0.87\textsuperscript{a} & 0.70\textsuperscript{a} & 0.72\textsuperscript{a} & -0.30 & -0.23$\\

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

I obtain following error:

```
l.179 & \rho
            \textsubscript{w} & \rho\textsubscript{d} & \%Min & \%Ash & \%O...?
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post complete code people can compile to reproduce the problem. Generally, this is essential. In this case, it isn't as the error is clear: `\rho` is not defined in text mode. You need `$\rho$` and then you will want to use e.g. `_d` rather than `\textsuperscript{d}`. So, e.g. `$\rho_{d}$`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{table}

\caption{Pearson’s coefficient of mechanical properties with different compositional parameters.}

\label{tab:4}

\begin{tabular}{lllllll}

\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

& $\rho_{\rm w}$ & $\rho_{\rm d}$ & $\%Min$ & $\%Ash$ & $\%Org_{\rm w}$ & $\%H_{\rm 2}$O %this isthe faulty line!!
\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\\
\textit{E} & 0.55\textsuperscript{a} & 0.92\textsuperscript{a} & 0.93\textsuperscript{a} & 0.81\textsuperscript{a} & -0.14 & 0.14
\\
$\textit{k}$ & $0.31$ & $0.87\textsuperscript{a}$ & $0.70\textsuperscript{a}$ & $0.72\textsuperscript{a}$ & $-0.30$ & $-0.23$
\\[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

`$` was missing in the symbols

Comment: `\rm` etc. have been obsolete for 20+ years and ought not be used in LaTeX documents unless you are compiling stuff requiring 2.09.